# JavaCC handle unknown token

Tags: java, lexical-analysis, javacc

I have some troubles using JavaCC in a project. I'm trying to build a lexical analyzer and I need to edit only certain tokens.

In short:

- if there is an `=` or `if` statement, do something (edit code and print);
- else do nothing (only print)

I can't handle the second part where there are "unknown" tokens.

Comment: http://eriklievaart.com/blog/javacc2.html see the section that describes <*> TOKEN : { <UNKNOWN: ~[]> }

Comment: Thanks, that guide solved my problems. At first I made a bad use of the states of the analyzer.